# Android service not updating variables in time

Tags: java, android, service, httprequest

---

I'm just wondering why my static variables declared in my Activity are not updated by my Service in time for the getTimeStamp() method call. Is this because the service is run concurrently and if so is there anyway I can give it a token which ensures it finishes before underneath code is run. You can see this in the validation method. The service is fired first which for instance will update the 'type' variable. However when the program gets to getTimeStamp() 'type' is still null even though it should now equal "Login".
Thanks,

This is my Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//TAG.
public static final String TAG = "BOE_TEST";

//UI elements.
Button TestNow;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//Timer.
Timer repeatTask = new Timer();

//Global variables and data structures.
int repeatInterval = 10000 * 1; // 10 sec
static Boolean success = true;
static String type;
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
static int count;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.listview_each_item, android.R.id.text1, values);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    TestNow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_test);
    repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    validation("Login");
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, repeatInterval);


    TestNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    validation("Login");
                }
            });

        }
    });


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void validation(String validate) {
    Intent i;
    i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginService.class);
    MainActivity.this.startService(i);
    MainActivity.this.stopService(i);

    values.add(0, getTimeStamp());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    try {
        if (success == true) {
            listView.getChildAt(count).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#009900"));
            count++;
        } else {
            listView.getChildAt(count).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cc0000"));
            count++;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
}


public static String getTimeStamp() {
    String s = "";
    String whiteSpaces = "         ";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");//Date
    s += "\n" + "Time: " + sdf.format(new Date()) + whiteSpaces ;
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");//Time
    Date date = new Date();
    s += "Date: " + sdf.format(date) + whiteSpaces+ "/*" + type + "*/";
    return s;
}


}
```

This is my Service

```
public class LoginService extends Service {

//TAG
private static final String TAG = "loginService";


//final variables
private static final String email = "xxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String login = "login";
private static final String BOE_LOGIN = "http://thebookofeveryone.com/account/";


@Override

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Login task = new Login();
    task.execute();

    return START_STICKY;
}





 public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(BOE_LOGIN);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", login));

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 400) {
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response error: "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }


        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseString;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
       MainActivity.type="Login";

        if(s.contains("We could not find a matching account")){
            Log.i(TAG,"Login Failed");
            createNotification("Login Failed");
            MainActivity.success = false;


        }else{
            Log.i(TAG,"Login Successfull");
            MainActivity.success = true;


        }


}

}

public void createNotification(String s) {

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.boelogo);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.boelogo)
                    .setLargeIcon(icon)
                    .setContentTitle( getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(s);


    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(001,builder.build());


   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you stopping the service straight away? It may not be executing because you are stopping it straight after you start it.

Comment: I thought I seen it some example code somewhere. I've tried that before however and It doesnt make a  difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a LocalBroadcastManager in the service, When I finished the service I fired the broadcast and had the method in my Activity to listen for it

Service

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

}

   private void sendResult() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("sendResult");
    sendLocationBroadcast(intent);
}

private void sendLocationBroadcast(Intent intent){
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Activity

//In onCreate()

```
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("sendResult"));

}


  private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       validation();
    }
};
```